# Vnstat on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vnstat

I'm completely new to Ubuntu.
Can somebody please help me and give me a step by step installation instructions for Vnstat. When I try to install it the database never updates. Thanks in advance. / Anders

Answer (score 1):

You can install using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

You can check if the service is running by running:

```
sudo service vnstat status
```

**EDIT: You may not see any errors, if you see `Active: active (running)` on the third line, the program was installed and the service installed correctly.**

Please update your question with any errors that are out-printed. It should take some time to collect data and put it in the database. When you type `vnstat` in a terminal and press enter you will see a message:

```
                      rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
eth0: Not enough data available yet.
```

Where `eth0` is replaced with a set of your network adapters with the same message next to it.

Hope this helps!